# c# string array to JS array

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to use C# string array in JS plugin with razor syntax.

**C# Code:** *(in cshtml)*

```
@{
    string[] extentions = new string[] { "jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg", "pdf" };
}
```

**JS Code :**

```
  $('#file').filer({
        limit: 2,
        maxSize: 4000,
        extensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg", "pdf"],
        ...
  })
```

**JS Code with C# string[]:**

```
  $('#file').filer({
        limit: 2,
        maxSize: 4000,
        extensions: '@extentions',
        ...
  })
```

In this case I get `System.String[]` and if I use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(extentions)` I get something like this:

```
[&quot;jpg&quot;,&quot;png&quot;,&quot;gif&quot;,&quot;jpeg&quot;,&quot;pdf&quot;]
```

What is the best way convert c# string array to Js array in the format that I want?

Comment: Why not using plain javascript array (if the C# array is not coming from server)?

Comment: @amirmishori maybe server version is used somewhere else in the view at server side..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(extentions))
```

`Html.Raw` ensures that argument will not be html-encoded, so you won't get `&quot;` instead of `"` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
    <text>[</text>
    foreach (string extension in extensions)
    {
        <text>"@extension", </text>
    }
    <text>]</text>
}
```

The code above will produce the output:

```
["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg", "pdf", ]
```

This is done by using the `<text></text>` tag which allows you to insert markup between the tags to be displayed within the View.
At the start, a `[` char is inserted. Then, it loops through each extension and outputs `"extension",`. After the loop is completed, it inserts a `]` char to end the valid JavaScript array.